# Bag of Strings are not persisted for all Grails domain objects in batch import

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I bumped into a weird problem when importing `User` domain objects in JSON format.
We have an importer service which loops through a JSONArray that is imported from an external service. The service logic has a fallback for a situation where the user does not have any `languages` in the JSON.
The weird part is that if the JSON contains hundreds of objects, only the first 200 or so users have default language correctly assigned to them after the import.  **But**, if I manually flush the Hibernate session with `user.save(flush: true)` instead of `user.save()` on every iteration, all users have the default language.

Simplified domain:

```
class User {
    String firstname
    String surname
    // ..

    static hasMany = [languages: String]
    static mapping = {
        languages cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}
```

The service code looks like this:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "en"

List<User> importUsers() {
    JSONArray users = remoteService.getUsers()
    users?.collect { JSONObject o ->
        User user = User.findById(o.getLong("id")) ?: new User()
        // some setters omitted

        o.optJSONArray("languages")?.each { String lang ->
            user.addToLanguages(lang.toLowerCase())
        }
        if (!user.languages) {
            user.addToLanguages(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE)
        }

        //user.save(failOnError: true)
        user.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
    }
}
```

I'd like to know why this is happening. There are no errors in the logs in either of the cases.

Thanks.

EDIT: Grails version 2.4.3

Comment: Does the call to  remoteService.getUsers() return any data ? From the code everything looks fine.

Comment: Yes, the data is ok.

Comment: is there a possibility of o being null  ? You may get a null pointer exception. I don't see any thing wrong with the code, I have similar code like this and works fine

Comment: I may have to try and create a reproducible test case, because I cannot find anything wrong with the code either.